# Using dynamic routes with AJAX calls?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I followed the tutorial http://christianvarga.com/simple-infinite-scroll-with-rails-and-jquery/
to implement an infinite scroll in my site.

The thing is, my `Photo Controller` Actions (latest photos, zone, category....) all use the `:index` template -> They use `render :index`

Thats a problem, because in the above tutorial, he uses static routes:

In index.js file:

```
$('a.load-more-spots').attr('href', '#{spots_ultimos_path page: @photos.next_page}');
```

In view:

```
<%= link_to 'Load More Photos', spots_ultimos_path(:page => @photos.next_page), :class => 'load-more-spots', :remote => true if @photos.next_page %>
```

Is there a way to have dynamic routes so I can use different routes within the same call?

Something like:

```
  $('a.load-more-spots').attr('href', '#{DYNAMIC_PATH page: @photos.next_page}');
    <%= link_to 'Load More Photos', DYNAMIC_PATH(:page => @photos.next_page), :class => 'load-more-spots', :remote => true if @photos.next_page %>
```

Thanks!

Comment: why are you trying to pass dynamic url to javascript code and not pull the url from DOM links themselves?

Comment: What do you mean with pull the url from DOM links themselves?